# Using transformations to solve question surrounding correlation of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vectors, covariance, correlation

[image]

While studying statistical inference and data-analysis, I came across this question. I have been able to show part (a) of this question already myself, but I don't know how to solve part (b). Can anyone help me with that?

(a) Show that
$$
\text{Cor}(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{X}_2) = \frac{\mathbf{a}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \mathbf{b}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{a}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{11} \mathbf{a}} \sqrt{\mathbf{b}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22} \mathbf{b}}}
$$

(b) Use appropriate transformations to show that
$$\max_{\mathbf{a}\neq\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{b}\neq\mathbf{0}} \text{Cor}(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{X}_2) = \max_{\mathbf{u}\neq\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}} \frac{(\mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{M} \mathbf{v})^2}{(\mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{u})(\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{v})}
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @AnotherUser I have put the most important formulas into the question

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[XX^\top] = E \left[ \begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X_1^\top & X_2^\top \end{pmatrix} \right] = E \left[\begin{pmatrix} X_1X_1^\top & X_1X_2^\top \\ X_2X_1^\top & X_2X_2^\top \end{pmatrix} \right]
$$
so
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(a^\top X_1, b^\top X_2) = E[a^\top X_1 (b^\top X_2)^\top] = E[a^\top X_1X_2^\top b] = a^\top\Sigma_{12}b
$$
as well as
$$
\operatorname{Var}(a^\top X_1) = E[a^\top X_1X_1^\top a] = a^\top \Sigma_{11} a
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}(b^\top X_2) = E[b^\top X_1X_1^\top b] = b^\top \Sigma_{22} b
$$
so substituting into
$$
\operatorname{Cor}(a^\top X_1, b^\top X_2) = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(a^\top X)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(a^\top X_1)\operatorname{Var}(b^\top X_2)}}
$$
gives part (a). For part (b), assuming that $X$ is non-degenerate normal (e.g. every component has positive variance) then we have that $\Sigma_{11}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ are positive-definite and thus there are some (symmetric, invertible) matrices  $\Sigma_{11}^{1/2}, \Sigma_{22}^{1/2}$ that square to $\Sigma_{11}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$. Put $u = \Sigma_{11}^{1/2} a$ and $v = \Sigma_{22}^{1/2}b$, so that
$$
\begin{align*}
\max_{a \neq 0, b \neq 0}\operatorname{Cor}(a^\top X_1, b^\top X_2) &= \max_{a \neq 0, b \neq 0} \frac{a^\top \Sigma_{12} b}{\sqrt{a^\top \Sigma_{11} a} \sqrt{b^\top \Sigma_{22} b}} \\
&= \max_{a \neq 0, b \neq 0} \frac{a^\top \Sigma_{11}^{1/2}\Sigma_{11}^{-1/2} \Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{1/2}\Sigma_{22}^{-1/2} b}{\sqrt{a^\top \Sigma_{11}^{1/2}\Sigma_{11}^{1/2} a} \sqrt{b^\top \Sigma_{22}^{1/2} \Sigma_{22}^{1/2} b}} \\
&= \max_{u \neq 0, v \neq 0} \frac{u^\top M v}{\sqrt{u^\top u}\sqrt{v^\top v}}
\end{align*}
$$
and since maximizing the square is the same maximization problem, this reduces to
$$
\max_{u \neq 0, v \neq 0} \frac{(u^\top M v)^2}{(u^\top u)(v^\top v)}
$$
as desired.

Edit: changed Cov to Cor

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there is something I don't understand. How come $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[XX^\top]$ instead of $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[XX^\top] - E[X]E[X]^\top$?

Comment: @daisies "since maximizing the square is the same maximization problem, this reduces to [...]" I don't understand this part : I agree that in this case the two problems have the same argmax, however there is no reason to believe that
$$\max_x f(x) = \max_x f(x)^2 $$
in general. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @LuciusAeliusSeianus Sorry, it should be the latter, e.g. $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[(X - E[X])(X - E[X])^T]$ but everything works out the same (pretend I said that things were centered first!).

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike No you are not missing anything as far as I am aware (and the two problems don't have the same max, unless the max is 0 or 1). But such is the problem as posed - certainly the mechanics of finding such a maximum would be mostly the same, so often people write things like the given problem.